# Having problems with making an .exe with cx_freeze with python and pygame, including additional files

Tags: python, pygame, cx-freeze

I'm having trouble creating an .exe file with cx_Freeze. I'm trying to use [this](http://pastebin.com/kRFX0QEf) Pygame game which needs some .png's, .gif's and .ogg's to run. I have tried to compile a simple Python only (no pygame or additional files) using the commmand line and a setup.py, but neither worked and I'm a bit out of my death.

I have installed cx_Freeze and checked it worked with ''import cx_freeze' in the IDLE not throwing an error. I'm using Python 3.3 on Windows 7 with the correct versions of pygame and cx_freeze for my python version.

Can anyone assist me in creating this .exe?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problems you're having? Start with the simple Python file - what do you do? Do you see any errors?

Comment: @Thomas K I just don't know what to put in setup.py and how to include the files and what to do with the 'diff' or 'build' folders - the cx_Freeze documentation I've found online is Yiddish to me... I really need someone to walk me through it.

Comment: You can try running `cxfreeze-quickstart` to create a setup.py file. If that doesn't work, there's an example file [shown here](http://cx_freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/distutils.html) that you could copy and modify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To include files in your `.exe` you should write a `setup.py` file that is similar to this:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

exe=Executable(
     script="file.py",
     base="Win32Gui",
     icon="Icon.ico"
     )
includefiles=["file.ogg","file.png",etc]
includes=[]
excludes=[]
packages=[]
setup(

     version = "0.0",
     description = "No Description",
     author = "Name",
     name = "App name",
     options = {'build_exe': {'excludes':excludes,'packages':packages,'include_files':includefiles}},
     executables = [exe]
     )
```

Comment: Thanks that's fantastic. Would pygame be a package or an includes? And would I put other native modules I've imported like time and random in there too? Thanks again.

Comment: From my experiences you don't need to add pygame anywhere. My exe works when i don't put pygame anywhere in the setup.py script. The same goes with the other modules.

Comment: Yes, you must first change to the directory with the files in it, then type 'python setup.py build'.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean Windows cmd line. It says: 'python' is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes windows cmd line. That's interesting. I'm not sure. It works on my computer. Perhaps it is a python 3.3 thing. (I have python 3.2). Where have you installed python? Try typing in the full location (e.g. C:\python\python.exe) instead of just "python". I am not exactly sure if this will work but it's worth the shot.

Comment: @jellyberg make sure you add python path (eg. C:\Python32\) to PATH environment variables as in http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Comment: Fantastic! With a little font fiddling I've got it all working, thanks again @Anthony.