# Compiled with cx_Freeze, now .exe throws ImportError: No module named BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, compilation, cx-freeze

How do I force cx_Freeze to include all required dependencies? I've tried to compile using `cxfreeze script.py --include-modules=BeautifulSoup`

but get this error:

`ImportError: No module named 'BeautifulSoup'`

Comment: Use `bs4` instead of `BeautifulSoup`

Comment: @Christian Thanks! Compiled successfuly using `bs4`, but still getting `ImportError: No module named 'BeautifulSoup'` when running the .exe

Comment: to make clear, can you run your python file on compiler machine ?

Comment: @cihanpesend Yes, works fine with no issues, so I know BeautifulSoup is present and working.

Comment: Is BeautifulSoup installed inside a zipped egg? cx_Freeze can have trouble finding modules inside zip files.

Comment: Did you include 'BeautifulSoup' in the setup file?

Comment: @Anothony, what setup file? I am just running `cxfreeze script.py --include-modules=BeautifulSoup` from command line. Is there a setup file I should be including?

Comment: The way I do it is create a setup file, then run the command `python setup.py build`. A setup file provides a better way to include modules and other files. The doc page for the `setup.py` file can be found on http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/distutils.html. You can also view the template that I use here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16065060. Try it out. It might work better than using the cx_freeze script. Hope this helped. Let me know if this solved your problem. If it did I will post it as an answer.

Comment: maybe you need to include `lxml` module explicitly in `packages`